# Python: Joining files in a list

Tags: python, list, file, concatenation

I am new to Python and am trying to join files that currently exist together in the same list into one file.

They share the same columns. What I have looks something like this:

> File_A
>      A     B     C
>      1...
>      2...
>      3...
>
> File_B
>      A    B     C
>      4...
>      5...
>      6...

And what I want to create is:

> File_C
>      A    B     C
>      1...
>      2...
>      3...
>      4...
>      5...
>      6...

What I tried is this (in the list "files"):

```
import fileinput
with open(file_c,'w') as fout:
    for line in fileinput.input(file_a, file_b):
        fout.write(line);
```

No dice. I end up with repeated lines for eternity.

I have tried other code as well to no avail. I know that I am doing something stupid, but I am not knowledgeable enough to know what that thing is.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose these are `csv` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate over each file object and write the lines  to a new file:

```
with open("input1.txt") as f, open("input2.txt") as f2,open("output.txt","w") as f3:
    f2.next() # skip header to avoid writing  A B C twice
    for line in f:
        f3.write(line)
    f3.write("\n") # separate last line from file 1 and first of file 2
    for line in f2:
        f3.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long running the process is, you could get away with

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(open('file_a').readlines())
    out.writelines(open('file_b').readlines()[1:])
```